# No segmentation fault without malloc

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc

There is a table that should grow following a determined function. Each time the table is full, the function addMemory is called, doubling the current table->table size. Everything seems to be working OK, however, and just to test the program, I commented the addMemory call, so I was expecting a segmentation fault as no new memory is requested to the OS, but it didn't fail, and it is actually writing data next to malloc'ed memory space without any errors.
I wonder why is this happening??

the code is here:

```
 int main(){
    //user* newUser = (user*)malloc(BASE_SIZE*sizeof(user));
    user* newUser = (user*)malloc(sizeof(user));

    userTable* table = (userTable*)malloc(sizeof(userTable));
    newUser->age = 1000;
    table->length = 0;
    table->table= newUser;
    table->length++;

    int i = 0;
    int memlimit = 1000;
    for(i = 1; i < memlimit; i++){
        if(memZone(table->length-1) != memZone(table->length)){
//this is the line that asks for more memory 
            addMemory((void*)table,"userTable");
            printf("mem pos =%i, age = %i\n",table->length,table->table[i-1].age);
        }
        table->table[i].age = (1000 + i);
        table->length++;

    }

    printf("All memory have been successfully allocated \n");
    int anything;
    while(scanf("%i",&anything)){
        reduceMemory((void*)table,"userTable");
        printf("Age = %i \n",table->table[table->length - 1].age);

    }
}
```

Struct definitions are these ones:

```
typedef struct {
    /* Username unique for this user in the system */
    char username[25];

    /* User name */
    char name[100];

    /* Age */
    unsigned int age;

    /* User city */
    char city[128];

} user;

/* Table of users */
typedef struct {
    /* Array of users */
    user* table;
    /* Number of registers in the table */
    int length;
} userTable;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern C libraries, malloc generally just allocates memory from *larger blocks* allocated by the kernel. It doesn't go to the kernel to request more memory every time, that would be inefficient.

So the CPU and the OS kernel probably have no clue that anything is going wrong, but this is invalid code with undefined behaviour, so don't do this. In particular, the next call to malloc could reallocate memory you are already using for something else.

Comment: This is the kind of answer I am looking for, thank you!